# How can I deal with connection problem when I use NSData?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdata, nsurl

One init method of NSXMLParser is initWithData:(NSData *data).
When I init the NSData like this,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://221.34.21.9"];
NSData *date = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

if the IP address cannot be reached,
my app will wait for that address's response forever.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to get the data through a `NSURLConnection`, which will have a timeout value, as described in the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fmac%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FConceptual%2FURLLoadingSystem%2FTasks%2FUsingNSURLConnection.html&ei=eKeJTfrGF4zmsQP-0viQDA&usg=AFQjCNGRRwTU980xlw3PtXe1cT8I35dGrg&sig2=cO-8nVmg2FjNL9YT_qkZiQ). This should give you a hint; the guide has more complete sample code:

```
// Create an NSURLRequest object with your desired URL and timeout value
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://221.34.21.9"]
                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                      timeoutInterval:15.0];
// Begin a connection using that request
// Assign a delegate object that will get callbacks when things happen
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Delegate methods are described in the [NSURLConnection Class Reference](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fmac%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FReference%2FFoundation%2FClasses%2FNSURLConnection_Class%2F&ei=kbKJTcXkAo-4sAOGq8j6Cw&usg=AFQjCNEulpFY25jvfnKWOjaTDopyPK1M3g&sig2=vGMeY5j7oRAHz4yJNhhjfg) You are probably most interested in `connection:didRecieveData` and `connection:didFailWithError:`

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Internet Reacheability, from [Apple Reaceability example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).
It is a test which will allow you to know if your internet connection is reachable.